# Java Multiples of 3

Tags: java

```
public class MultipleOfThree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N;
        N = 3;

        for (N = 3; N <= 21; N = N + 3) {
            System.out.println( N );
        }
    }
}
```

Got this output in a vertical line.
3
6
9
12
15
18
21

However, I needed this output in a horizontal line

The first 7 multiples of 3 are 3  6  9  12  15 18 21

Please help!

Comment: System.out.print(N + " ");

Comment: `IntStream.iterate(3, i -> i + 3).limit(21 / 3)
             .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
System.out.print( N + " " );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (N = 3; N <=21; N = N + 3) {
    System.out.println( N );
}
```

to (and I would prefer to limit the scope of `N`), and adding your preamble text like

```
// int N;
// N = 3;
System.out.print("The first 7 multiples of 3 are ");
for (int N = 3; N <= 21; N += 3) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", N);
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: How would the output be The first 7 multiples of 3 are 3 6 9 12 15 18 21

Comment: I think I need to add two variable a=7 and b=3, right?

Answer (score 0):

The `println()` method creates a new line at the end of each output. What you want to use is the `printf()` method. Be sure to include spaces between the numbers.

```
System.out.print("The first 7 multiples of 3 are ");
for (int N = 3; N <= 21; N += 3) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", N);
}
```

Comment: For some reason.. 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 isn't in the output tho